# IntelliJ - How to run only one (main) class when inside whole project

Tags: java, class

I have a project in InteliJ with 'src' folder and many subfolders under it.
 Currently there is a problem with one of the classes in one of subfolders (`src/somefolder/Somefile.java`).

I would like to test running ONLY ONE (main) java class.
Created java file in `src/Hello.java` with following code:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I right click on edit screen and select RUN -> Hello.main() it start compiling/parsing EVERYTHING (every folder and sub-folder in whole project directories) and instead of printing `Hello!` for that one file - it gives error:
`...Error in src/somefolder/Somefile.java`

How can I limit the scope and compile/run only one file (the one currently editing) and ignore ALL other folders, files etc.?

Comment: Have you tried running your main() method inside in a test (a JUnit test that calls it for example)?

Answer (score 0):

A very useful feature in IntelliJ is [Scratch files](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/scratch-files/).

You can create one with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + insert (default shortcut).
Here you can paste the code you want to run. After you close the tab the file will be deleted so make sure if you edit anything to update the original file.

Comment: I tried creating a scratch file on my project, clicked to run it and it still compiled my entire project... not sure this will solve the OPs issue